# How to read the string and long features in tensorflow

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

The tensorflow, I can't read string,long, only short float allowed? Why?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Data sets
IRIS_TRAINING = "seRelFeatures.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "seRelFeatures.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TRAINING, target_dtype=np.int)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TEST, target_dtype=np.int)
```

here is the error

```
/home/xuejiao/anaconda2/bin/python /home/xuejiao/Desktop/HDSO_DirectAnswer/training_testing/dnn_semiSuper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xuejiao/Desktop/HDSO_DirectAnswer/training_testing/dnn_semiSuper.py", line 9, in <module>
    training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TRAINING, target_dtype=np.int)
  File "/home/xuejiao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py", line 47, in load_csv
    target[i] = np.asarray(ir.pop(target_column), dtype=target_dtype)
  File "/home/xuejiao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 482, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: ''

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is `ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: ''`. It simply that you are entering empty string instead of an integer (or string presentation of an integer). I'd check data in CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved this problem by myself, this mistake mean

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: ''
```

I have some empty cell, but actually I don't have on the view.
After I check it, it cased by I delete the last column but I just delete the content didn't delete the cells, so from view can't find any empty